# ¿Cómo eliminar registros duplicados al insertar en una tabla con SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy realizando un sistema donde por alguna razón me duplica los datos al momento de insertarlos.
Mi idea para resolver esto es comparar los registros que se vayan insertando al mismo tiempo y eliminarlo esto con ayuda de un disparador (trigger), pero aún no he podido llegar a la solución. Estoy usando ASP clásico.

Mi tabla está estructurada de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado documentación pero no doy en el objetivo.

Este es mi código que llevo pero claramente está mal, pero podría ser la idea.

```
CREATE TRIGGER postulaciones ON postulaciones
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM postulaciones t      
              WHERE id_usu=id_usu
              )
    INSERT INTO postulaciones
    SELECT id_usu
    FROM postulaciones
    GO
```

Esta es mi estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu problema es que se insertan filas duplicadas, deberías atacar eso en primer lugar, desde el mismo diseño de la tabla y los índices se tendría que  impedir la posibilidad de que entren filas duplicadas.  De cualquier forma, como solución paliativa, un trigger podría ser, pero lo estas planteando mal, deberías chequear si ya existe alguna fila en cuyo caso Si disparar un error que impida la inserción de duplicados. ¿Qué motor de base de datos? ¿Podrías agregar la estructura e índices de la tabla?

Comment: Según lo que propones, sería más fácil agregar una clave primaria o única que ignore duplicados.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Además de que el camino escogido es **muy malo**, no veo ninguna fila duplicada. El único registro que tiene (según el trigger) id_usu = 62, no en todas sus columnas tienen valores. `fecha_captura`. ¿Cuál se descarta?, Ya que no encuentras donde se produce, y si la inserción viene en la misma sentencia? ¿cual descartas? Creo que te estás metiendo en un problemón, que te va a salir mal. Si estás con una página ASP, puedes depurar el código paso por paso. Y además tener el profiler abierto, para saber donde se disparan las inserciones. No te será difícil buscar como se depura y utiliza profiler.